# delay messing up with classes (if else)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im stuck in the following code:

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 5) {

         $("#logomenu").delay(750).queue(function () {
             $("#logomenu").toggleClass("logofrontgo", true);
             $("#logomenu").dequeue();
         });
     } else {
         $("#logomenu").toggleClass("logofrontgo", false);
     }
```

i need the delay when the IF condition is satisfied, but i dont need it in the ELSE. but... when the code enter in the "ELSE", sometimes it executes the IF condition in sequence, I think its because the IF was satisfied right before the else was executed, and then, when he enters the ELSE, it executes the IF condition after the delay (750ms) and then evertyhing brokes..

any help? thanks!

Comment: Please don't copy and paste tabs into SO. It causes formatting problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it would be easier to just use a timeout, and toggle both the delay and the class with a switch :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
   var _switch = $(window).scrollTop() > 5;

   clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer') );

   $(this).data('timer', 
       setTimeout(function() {
           $("#logomenu").toggleClass( "logofrontgo", _switch );
       }, _switch ?  750 : 0)
   );
});
```

Comment: the ideia looks pretty good, im trying to use it but with no sucess, this exaclty code looks that will work, dont you think?.. i tried some things but i failed to use it, could you give me a hand? thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Tried it [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqVPu/), once you scoll down, the delay kicks in, and after 750ms the class is added. Once you scoll up to the top, the class is removed right away ?

Comment: i make it work, it was a mistake of mine in another part of the code that was broking your code ;p its working nicely now, thanks to you :)

Comment: im trying to use this code to the inverse situation (delay in case false), i can use the same "timer"?, i made someting like this, but dosent work: setTimeout(function() { $("#logomenu").toggleClass( "logofrontgo", _switch );}, _switch ?  0 : 750) .... Another thing, the class is apllied just when the user stops scrolling down the page... until that, the class isent applied... theres a fix for it? ty!!